# posting an object through deep nesting in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

There are a few of us working on a web api, and one of the moderators wanted to have a community which has many events, and those events have many tickets.

Here's what the routes.rb file looks like.

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :communities, :defaults => { :format => 'json' } do
    resources :events do
      resources :tickets
    end
  end
end
```

I've gotten my RSpec requests tests for the tickets to work, all except for POST.

Here's the tickets controller

```
class TicketsController < ApplicationController

  before_action :set_community,  only: [:create]
  before_action :set_event,      only: [:index, :create]
  before_action :set_ticket,     only: [:show, :update, :destroy]

  def index
    @tickets = @event.tickets
    render json: @tickets
  end

  def create
    @ticket = @event.tickets.build(ticket_params)
    if @ticket.save
      render json: @ticket, status: :created, location: [@community, @event, @ticket]
    else
      render json: @ticket.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end


  def show
    render json: @ticket
  end

  def update
    if @ticket.update(ticket_params)
      render json: @ticket
    else
      render json: @ticket.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end

  def destroy
    if @ticket.destroy
      render json: @ticket
    else
      render json: @ticket.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end

  private
  def ticket_params
    params.require(:ticket).permit(:name, :cost, :quantity,
                              :sale_starts_at, :sale_ends_at)
  end

  def set_ticket
    @ticket = Ticket.find(params[:id])
  end

  def set_event
    @event = Event.find(params[:event_id])
  end

  def set_community
    @community = Community.find(params[:community_id])
  end

end
```

In the create function I wrote `@event.tickets.build(ticket_params)`,
but I got a validation error and it said I need the community.

I thought`@community.event.tickets.build(ticket_params)`would work but I get a no method error from `@community`.

It's maybe not the best practice to deeply nest like that, but I wonder how it could work.

Here are the models

```
class Community < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :events
  has_many :tickets, through: :event

  validates :name, presence: true
  validates :description, presence: true
end

class Event < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :community
  has_many :tickets

  validates :name, presence: true
  validates :description, presence: true
  validates :event_starts_at, presence:true
  validates :event_ends_at, presence:true

end

class Ticket < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :event
  belongs_to :community

  validates :name, presence: true
  validates :cost, presence: true,
                   numericality: { greater_than_or_equal_to: 0 }
  validates :quantity, presence: true,
                       numericality: { greater_than_or_equal_to: 1 }
  validates :sale_starts_at, presence: true
  validates :sale_ends_at, presence: true
end
```

I tried to write `belongs_to :community, through: :event` in the ticket model, but for some reason I get this error:
`ArgumentError: Unknown key: :through. Valid keys are: :class_name, :anonymous_class, :foreign_key, :validate, :autosave, :foreign_type,` etc...

Any help would be great, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you should setup the relation between ticket and community to go through `events` instead of duplicating the foreign key.

```
class Ticket < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :event
  has_one :community, through: :event
end
```

This will cause Event to work as a join table which is a good thing since ActiveRecord only keeps track of one foreign key relationship when your create resources from an association.

The difference between `has_one` and `belongs_to` is that `belongs_to` places the foreign key column on *this* model, while `has_one` places it on the other model. Thats why a `belongs_to through:` relationship is not possible.

Comment: Thank you very much max, I think this has gotten me on the right track. I don't quite have everything figured out yet, but I can post now! Because a ticket is "under" a community, it didn't cross my mind that `has_one` would work, but it went through for sure. Thanks again!

Comment: If this answer helped you you should accept the answer by pressing the checkmark on the right side.